# How I run C progamme with Input in Netbeans

Tags: c, netbeans

I try This code

```
#include <stdio.h>

   int main() { 
        int testInteger;
        printf("Enter an integer: \n");
        scanf("%d", &testInteger);  
        return 0;
    }
```

But in Netbeans, I can't Run this code because It only blank output

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsuEb.png)

I have same err in VS code but I fix it with run in terminal

Can you help me

Comment: Nop It show first O/P But not get Input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is about Netbean's internal terminal/console section. The internal console is not able to run `scanf` function. So use an external terminal for your project. To do this:

first right click on your project, and select properties.
In that window select `"Run"` tab at the bottom.
in there, there is `"Console Type"`, change this console type from `"internal terminal"` to `"external terminal"`.
That is all.

Answer (score 0):

try this code
Add a space in scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

   int main() { 
        int testInteger;
        printf("Enter an integer: \n");
        scanf(" %d", &testInteger);  
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: A bit more explanation would be useful. Why would that space fix the missing output of `printf`?

Comment: With a space before scanf it will ignore the white spaces.

Comment: And this will affect the missing *output* in what way?

Comment: I dont have sure because I dont have Netbeans installed but you can try